# How to move Woocommerce product meta to right column?

Tags: woocommerce

How do I move Woocommerce product meta and the social share to the right column in single product page?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UCgJ.png)

Comment: It all comes down to the theme you use. You have to see how they implemented this part? Is it implemented with templates or with hooks? What theme do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Woocommerce product meta mostly implemented in two ways. (Templates and Hook) In my case, the product meta is using the templates approach which you can find in most of the theme folder wp_content/themes/YOURTHEMENAME/inc/woocommerce.php

add_action('thegem_woocommerce_single_product_right', 'thegem_socials_sharing', 55);
add_action('thegem_woocommerce_single_product_right', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 65);